# How to use an my iphone as a modem 3G for my computer

Tags: windows, iphone, tethering

I would like to use my iPhone as 3g modem connection for my PC. 
Can anyone let me know I can do so?

Answer (score 9):

What you want is called "[tethering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tethering)".

[Here](http://www.apple.com/iphone/iphone-3gs/tethering.html) you can find apple's official stance on it:
From that same page (when you click on 'How to use internet tethering'):

> ### Using iPhone as a Modem
>
> You can use iPhone 3G or later as a
>   modem to connect, or tether, your
>   computer to the Internet. You can
>   connect iPhone to your computer using
>   the Dock Connector to USB Cable, or
>   via Bluetooth.
>
> NOTE: Additional fees may apply.
>   Contact your carrier for more
>   information.
>
> Tethering works over the cellular data
>   network. You can’t share a Wi-Fi
>   connection to the Internet. If you
>   have a 3G connection, you can make and
>   receive phone calls while tethering.
>
> NOTE: To use iPhone as a modem with a
>   Mac computer, it must be running Mac
>   OS X version 10.5.7 or later.
>
> **Set up a
>   tethering connection:**
>
> 1. In Settings, choose General > Network > Internet Tethering.
> 2. Slide the Internet Tethering switch to On.
> 3. Connect iPhone to your computer:
>
>    - USB:  Connect your computer to iPhone, using the Dock
>        Connector to USB Cable. In your
>        computer’s Network services settings,
>        choose iPhone.
>
>      On a Mac, a pop-up window appears the first time you connect,
>        saying “A new network interface has
>        been detected.” Click Network
>        Preferences, configure the network
>        settings for iPhone, then click Apply.
>        On a PC, use the Network Control Panel
>        to configure the iPhone connection.
>    - Bluetooth:  On iPhone, choose Settings > General > Bluetooth
>        and turn on Bluetooth. Then refer to
>        the documentation that came with your
>        computer system software to pair and
>        connect iPhone with your computer.
>
> When you’re connected, a blue band
>   appears at the top of the screen.
>   Tethering remains on when you connect
>   with USB, even when you aren’t
>   actively using the Internet
>   connection.
>
> **Monitor your cellular data
>   network usage:**
>
> In Settings, choose General > Usage.

There's quite some [other ways](http://www.google.com/search?q=iphone+tethering) explained on the internet how to do it once you know which term to search for ;-)

Answer (score 0):

yeah there are a heap of apps around that will help you do it. The ones I've played around with involve creating a wireless network between the pc and iphone, and then activate 'tethering' via the 3rd party app.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have Internet Tethering, get PDANet on the iPhone and also on your desktop.  It works great.
http://ismashphone.com/2008/09/pdanet.html 
http://ismashphone.com/2009/06/activate-internet-tethering-now-on-iphone-os-30.html

Comment: Note, this requires jailbreaking the iPhone